# Could not find driver for postgres using laradock

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, docker, laradock

I am using the laradock and Postgres in my laravel project but when I try to run PHP artisan migrate it gives me the error, could not find the driver. below is my .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=postgres
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=vv
DB_USERNAME=default
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

When I run my project it fetches the data, but when I try to migrate it give the error, driver could not find and show me the error on this connection file,
laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671

Note: when I use MySQL it works fine, but when I use Postgres it gives me this error, and my postgres image on docker is working fine. My pgadmin connects to postgres

Comment: Do you run the `php artisan migrate` command inside the workspace container or the host terminal?

Comment: @Ebi brother, you save my day, thanks a lot, i was trying to run php artisan migrate without docker container workspace

Comment: run this command docker-compose exec workspace bash and then move to project directory, that works perfectly